# Javascript html5 Video add/remove class on certain time

Tags: javascript, html5-video

In pure JS (no jQuery).

Given is a html 5 video:

```
    <video>
      <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
```

and some links

```
    <a href="#" class="menu">Person 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">Person 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">Person 3</a>
```

How could I add "active" to a certain href if Video passes a specific point (and remove active from all others).

For example: 
Video passes second 3

```
    <a href="#" class="menu active">Person 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">Person 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">Person 3</a>
```

… if video passes second 6 add active to link from "Person 2" and so on.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate) event

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
   console.log(this.currentTime);

   if (this.currentTime >= 3) {
       // add class to first item
   }

   if (this.currentTime >= 6) {
      // add class to second item
   }

}, false);
```